# Find parent node position using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to find the parent node position from the child node in XSLT.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to find the parent node
>   position from the child node in
>   XSLT.

This is done entirely using XPath.

**The answer depends on what is the definition of "parent node position**:

```
count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

is the ordinal number of the parent among all upper-level elements

```
count(../preceding-sibling::node()) + 1
```

is the ordinal number of the parent among all upper-level nodes (including text-nodes, comments and PIs.

The above expression is the only correct one if the current node is an immediate child of the root `/` (such as top element, top-level comment or top-level processing instruction).

Comment: @VextoR, A first node, has no preceding siblings -- so its position is zero (number of preceding siblings) plus one. If you are Nth then your position is one plus the position of your immediate preceding sibling -- which (by induction) is the count of its preceding siblings plus one -- so your position is: (the count of your immediate preceding sibling's preceding siblings plus one) plus one. The expression in the brackets is exactly the count of *your* preceding siblings -- theirfore, your position is the count of your preceding siblings plus one. "Position" isn't XPath position here.