# Need to find parent node position from child

Tags: xslt

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tr> </w:tr>
  <w:tr> </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
     <w:tc>
        <p>i am here</p>
     <w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

I am using xslt 1.0.

It's a xml sample code for `table(w:tbl-->table,w:tr-->row,w:tc-->td)`. Now I am in w:tc template match. I want to know the position of parent node ie. w:tr (which is 3). How can i get it from the tc template itself?

Note I have put `<xsl:apply-templates>` in w:tc template match.

Comment: Why do you ask again the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312255/finding-parent-node-position-using-xslt)? And why this time you accept the same answer you rejected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find parent node position using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312255/find-parent-node-position-using-xslt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
```

If you want to consider parent position only relative to the elements like it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::w:tr)+1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am in need to get the cell position number from template. The following line might help some one 
**count(ancestor::w:tc/preceding-sibling::w:tc)**

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(parent::*/preceding-sibling::w:tr)"/>
```

It counts the preceding siblings of the parent node with respect to `w:tr` elements, which should be the same as the parents position in that table.

Comment: Small correction in this..have to do +1 to get the parent node position.